# Textbox disappears when I change width of initial sprite

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm attempting to draw a text box on the screen.  If I assign width and height to any value, as in the code below, I don't see anything drawn.  Why is this?  What is the use of width and height?  Adobe's docs say it's the width/height of the sprite in pixels.  Why would that occlude or prevent the drawing of a textbox or another box?  I assumed the width/height would set the area that this sprite could be drawn upon, but based on this, I'm probably wrong.

Thanks in advance.

-Nick

`package
{`

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import mx.core.* ;
import mx.collections.* ;
import flash.display.* ;
import flash.text.* ;

[SWF(width=1000,height=500)]
public class BareBones extends Sprite
{
    public var backBuffer:BitmapData;
    public var clearColor:uint = 0xFF0043AB;
    public var display_txt:TextField;
    public var i:uint = 0
    public function BareBones()
    { 
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, step);
        width = 1000;
        height = 500;
        display_txt = new TextField();
        display_txt.text = "Hello World!";
        addChild(display_txt);
    }

    private function step(event:Event) : void
    {
        i++;
        display_txt.text = i.toString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: just try to create the textfield, and afterwards set the width/height of the container. Still, don't fully understand what is your final goal...

Comment: I'm just trying to display a textfield.  I'm confused as to why setting the dimensions of the BareBones would cause the textfield to not display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `width` and `height` in the constructor, you're actually affecting the `scaleX` and `scaleY` variables, which in turn affect root's `transform.matrix`.

In order to know how to set `scaleX`, Flash works off the content that is inside the clip. For example if you have a MovieClip with a 100x100 box in it, and you set `width = 200`, Flash will calculate that you mean `scaleX = 2`.

However you are setting `width` and `height` on a clip with **nothing** in it. The consequence is that `scaleX` and `scaleY` are both being set to 0.

Comment: Does the TextField count as something?

Comment: I added a graphics.drawrect(0,0,1000,500) call in the step method, and attempted to set the width and height to 1000 and 500, and it draws nothing.  The textfield also disappeared. Perhaps I'm drawing this incorrectly.  My draw code is the following 6 lines.  I based this on sample code I found here: http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/11012.aspx
backBuffer = new BitmapData(1000, 500, false);
backBuffer.fillRect(backBuffer.rect, clearColor);
graphics.clear();
graphics.beginBitmapFill(backBuffer, null, false, false);
graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 1000, 500);
graphics.endFill();

Comment: @Nikhil: The TextField would count for something, but you haven't added it yet at the point where you set the width and height. Try changing the order of the statements.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It all makes sense now.  A bit unintuitive, but I've got a grip on it.